# Show Two Plots in Separate Windows Using Plots

Tags: julia

let's assume I have a file called plot.jl:

```
using Plotsfunction plotSine()
    x = LinRange(0,2π, 101)
    y = sin.(x)    gr()
    p = plot(x,y, title="Sine from 0 to 2π", xlabel="x", ylabel="y")
    display(p)
endfunction plotTwoFunctions()
    x = LinRange(0, 2, 101)
    y1 = exp.(x)
    y2 = log.(x)    gr()
    p = plot(x,y1, title="Two functions", xlabel="x x", ylabel="y")
    plot!(p, x,y2)
    display(p)
endplotSine()
plotTwoFunctions()
```

I starta REPL session and include it and it opens the window for the sine function plot but that get's instantly overwritten by the second function call.

Is there a blocking display() function? Can I somehow force a new window to open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `reuse=false` as in this example below:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
p1 = plot(rand(5))
p2 = plot(rand(50), reuse=false)
```

Comment: Thanks - ah I tried that with gr() before but it didn't work. Seems like I do have to use the pyplot(). But pyplot() is nice anyway so thanks.

Can I somehow set reuse=false after generating p2?

Because if I have two functions returning two plots I can't get that working.

Comment: Most likely it is possible via `gr` but  it is not part of the standard API and I have not been doing that. As  far as I know this would be the code to start with https://github.com/jheinen/GR.jl/blob/master/examples/gtk_ex.jl

Comment: Thanks - can't see why it is such a big hassle to show several plots in several windows. :( I'll recheck but I thought gr doesn't support the reuse property.